# Why I am having error after I click my image button many times

Tags: java, android

When I click the image button for more than 15 times it should stop functioning. What is the code that I can use here? 
I am new developer and I really need your help. I hope you can help me

**here is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                        setContentView(R.layout.main);                   

        ImageButton One = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnkick);
        One.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.kick1);  
                try
                {
                    mp.prepare();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {}
                catch (IllegalStateException e)
                {}
                mp.start();
            }
        });

    ImageButton two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnkick1);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.kick1);  
                try
                {
                    mp.prepare();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {}
                catch (IllegalStateException e)
                {}
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please, add your stacktrace

Comment: please how to add?

Comment: If you use Android Studio, click in `Android Monitor` option, after that you will see the log cat of your device under testing, after that you need to repeat the procedure for reproduce the crash in your app, in the log cat you'll see red text, copy and paste that for review the bug

Comment: but I am just using aide. is there an android monitor option in aide..

Comment: I decided to make this project on my aide because my android studio having an error. I having an error with gradle even if I have gradle

Comment: AFAIK AIDE has an `Android Monitor` but it shows it as `Log Cat` (if I remember well)  you should see in the options menu of the IDE (the three dots in the right upper corner). About your gradle problem, you should search for the error in google or post it in stack overflow

Comment: I found some red from logcat

Comment: 05-31 13:08:54.298 27300 27300 D   MediaPlayer                                  handleMessage msg:(6, 0, 0)
05-31 13:08:54.371 27300 27300 D   MediaPlayer                                  Don't notify duration to com.Virtual.Drummer!
05-31 13:08:54.387 27300 27300 E   MediaPlayer

Comment: how to fix it??

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
One.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
     {
        count=count+1;
        if(count<=15)
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.kick1);  
            try
            {
                mp.prepare();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }

    }
});

int counttwo=0;
 two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        counttwo=counttwo+1;
        if(counttwo<=15)
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.kick1);  
            try
            {
                mp.prepare();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    }
});
```

use this in your code.